# Property 'update' and 'quantity' doesn't exist on type '{ }'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6, angularfire

I'm watching the tutorial of Mosh Hamedani using the Angular version 6 but the problem is the tutorial version is 4. I'm working on the e-commerce project on AddToCart button where the product should increase it's quantity by clicking the button and updated in Firebase using productId and also if I try to add new product then id of that new product should add in AngularFire Database.
I've error in the last line of item.update() and item.quantity. Please go through the code and suggest me better solution. Thanks in advance

Here is the code.

shopping-cart.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Product } from '../model/product';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, ) { }

  private create() {
   return this.db.list('/shopping-cart').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    })
  }

  private getCart(cartId: String) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-cart/' + cartId);
  }

  private getItem(cartId:string, productId: String) {
   return this.db.object('/shopping-cart/' + cartId + '/items/' +productId);
  }

 private async getOrCreateCart() {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');

    if (cartId) return cartId;

    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;  
  }

  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCart();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);

    item$.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
      // I'am getting error in update() and quantity
      item.update({ product: product,quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 1});
    })
  }
}
```

Expected results are that after clicking on Add To cart button, the product quantity must be updated in firebase

Have a look at my other files(for reference)
1. home.component.html (Here is the button when clicked goes to .ts file as shown below)

```
<div class="card-footer">
    <button (click)="addToCart(product)" style="background: #2980b9; 
             color:white" class="btn btn-block">Add to Cart
    </button>
</div>
```

2. home.component.ts (the click event defined here)

```
addToCart(product:Product) {
     this.cartService.addToCart(product);
   }
```

and the last file
3. shopping-cart.service.ts

```
private async getOrCreateCart() {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');

    if (cartId) return cartId;

    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;  
  }

  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCart();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);

    item$.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
      item$.update({ product: product,quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 1});
    })
  }
```

Here are the error images:
1. The error is back
[image: Property quantity does not exist on type {}]
2. Now when I modify the above code of addToCart(product: Product) which is as:

```
async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCart();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);

    item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item: any) => {
      if(item.key != null) {
        item$.update({ product: product,quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 1});
      } else {
        item$.set( {product:product, quantity:1});
     }   
    });
  }
```

I get following error:
[image: The project compiles successfully, but key is undefined after clicking the button]

This is all I have... Please see the errors again and suggest a better solution... Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the information. Where is the `product` variable defined which you use on the click event?

Comment: Do you have your code on GitHub? This would be simpler if you could share your whole code.

Comment: the product variable pertains to Product interface model which is passed as parameter in addToCart(product:Product) method in component.... For your second question... No, I didn't upload the project on Github due to errors, once the errors are gone, I'll upload it

Comment: GitHub is intended for software development not just for storing finished code ;). It is hard for me to help if i only see a part of your code. But i think something goes wrong with this `product` variable. This should be an actual product which you have loaded from your database somehow.

Comment: OK I'll upload it on Github shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the update method on the value you get from the database. You have to use the update method on a database object.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md

I could not test it, let me know if it works.

```
async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCart();
    let itemRef = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);

    itemRef.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
      itemRef.update({ product: product,quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 1});
    })
 }
```

Comment: Wow superb... update() error gone, but, quantity in 'item.quantity' still persists... Error is same Property quantity doesn't exists on type '{ }'... but, project still got compiled successfully. Now the problem is TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined... when clicked on Add To Cart

Comment: Ok i think i have found the source code of your tutorial. I believe it should be product.$key not product.key. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response... In Angular 6 $key is replaced with just key, which was in Angular 4... Well, the problem is that it could not get the value from firebase via product model

Comment: Here is my product model for your reference              export interface Product {
    key: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    categories : string;
    imageUrl: string;
}

Comment: I have seen you changed quiet a bit of the tutorial code. I think the problem could be in the shopping-cart-item.ts in the model folder. In the original code there is no product property. Did you change something there and forgot to add the quantity property?

Comment: But how will I get the key which is expected to be retrieved from firebase... Mosh Hamedani e-commerce project is in Angular 4, whereas I've done it in Angular 6, thus I'am getting errors

Comment: Could you edit your question and show the complete error message? So we could see where in the code the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

Is your products.component.ts file looking like this?

**products.component.ts**

```
import { ShoppingCartService } from './../shopping-cart.service';
import { Product } from './../models/product';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ProductService } from './../product.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-products',
    templateUrl: './products.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './products.component.css' ]
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    products: Product[] = [];
    filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
    category: string;
    cart: any;
    subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(
        route: ActivatedRoute,
        productService: ProductService,
        private shoppingCartService: ShoppingCartService
    ) 
    {
        productService
            .getAll()
            .pipe(
                switchMap((products: Product[]) => {
                    this.products = products;
                    return route.queryParamMap;
                })
            )
            .subscribe((params) => {
                this.category = params.get('category');

                this.filteredProducts = this.category
                    ? this.products.filter((p) => p.category === this.category)
                    : this.products;
            });
    }

    async ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = (await this.shoppingCartService.getCart())
            .valueChanges()
            .subscribe((cart) => (this.cart = cart));
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Here look at the ngOnInit() function. 
Before .subscribe() you have to write .valueChanges()

That means you have to write

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = (await this.shoppingCartService.getCart())
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe((cart) => (this.cart = cart));
}
```

**shopping-cart.service.ts**

```
async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCart();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
    item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item) => {
        if (item.payload.exists()) {
            item$.update({ quantity: item.payload.exportVal().quantity + 1 });
        } else {
            item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1 });
        }
    });
}
```

I think it will work. Please inform me it works or not.